# DHTMLX Combo inside Ajax Panel in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, combobox, dhtmlx

I'm trying the combination of [DHTMLX Combo](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxCombo/index.shtml) and ASP.NET AJAX, but since it's simply a javascript and not .NET native it will post back ignoring the update panel. I need it working with AJAX, so what could I do?

If I could do that AJAX call manually it would help, but how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is an article](http://encosia.com/2007/07/13/easily-refresh-an-updatepanel-using-javascript/) that describes how you can refresh an UpdatePanel using Javascript. Does that help you at all?

Update: Since the solution as described in the article is so concise, I'll add it to  my answer to save future readers some time. In Javascript:

```
__doPostBack('updatePanelId', 'someArgument');
```